# how to remap the menu key on windows

Tags: windows, keyboard

I want to remap my menu key to another key,I use [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/hardware/drivers/hid/keyboard-and-mouse-class-drivers#code-snippet-2) to do it , but I can't find the key code of menu key.where can I find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referencing [here](https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/kbd/scancodes-1.html) and [here](http://www.quadibloc.com/comp/scan.htm), the scan code for the Window Menu key (in hex) is `e0 5d`

Virtual Key is `VK_MENU`, which is:

```
 #define VK_MENU           0x12
```

Answer (score 8):

The menu key is `e0 5d`

As a reference example, suppose you just got a Microsoft Surface device and are frustrated that the right control key is missing and in its place sits an unwanted context menu / right click key. Here's the fix:

**To remap the Menu key to right Control key:**

Using the Registry Editor (regedit.exe)

Create a new Binary Value named `Scancode Map` at the registry location

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout
```

and enter the Scancode Map value data:

```
00000000 00000000 02000000 1DE05DE0 00000000
```

Here the `1DE0` is the key code for the RCtrl key and `5DE0` is the menu key (in little endian order)

**To remap both the Menu key and Caps Lock keys to Control keys:**

Set Scancode Map to

```
00000000 00000000 03000000 1D003A00 1DE05DE0 00000000
```

Comment: "As a reference example, suppose..." - Literally the exact reason I wanted to do this, LOL

Comment: Don't forget to reboot.